# How to save complete webpage or HTML File in Android?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have an html file with images and text on server. I want to download that HTML file along with images. I have code for downloading the html file. But how can i download the images along with the HTML file?

```
public void myDownload(String myURL, String title, String year, String branch, String section) {

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myURL));
    request.setTitle("File Download");
    request.setDescription("Downloading....");

    //request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    //request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
    String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myURL, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myURL));

    //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/KiiTTimeTableData/" + year + "/" + branch + "/" + section + "/", nameOfFile);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/KiiTTimeTableData/" + year + "/" + branch + "/" + section + "/", nameOfFile);
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to parse the HTML you've downloaded for IMG tags, and download the images separately.  That or use a library meant for this sort of thing instead of downloadmanager.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSoup to load the html into a Document element,
then fetch all the img nodes and retrieve the image from the src attribute.

Consider the code example here: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/html/download-images-from-a-website-using-jsoup/